# Is res_query thread-safe?

Tags: c, linux, dns, thread-safety, resolver

Is res_query (`int res_query(const char *dname, int class, int type,unsigned char *answer,
int anslen);`) thread-safe?

I think so, because it writes its answer to an user-allocated buffer (in contrast to gethostbyname that uses a statically allocated buffer).

Does somebody know for sure?

Comment: [Doesn't seem to be MT safe](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=linux+res_query+multi+threaded&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: @Dummy00001: There's only one hit, where somebody claims that res_query is not threadsafe, because it overwrites the internal configuration variable _res. I found some older discussion (from 2002) on the BIND mailing list (libresolv and thus res_query is part of BIND), that _res should be thread-local, so I think that they already implemented this years ago.

Comment: btw, [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) advertises support for (async) name resolution. I bet they have better docs regarding MT-safeness. Good Luck.

Comment: @Dummy00001: Unfortunately I can't use another library, because res_query is called from a 3rd-party library.

Answer (score 2):

You were right that res_query is not threadsafe. You have to use res_nquery, which takes a 'res_state' argument first. From everything I've read, that is how the query should be done in a thread safe manner.